# random change of PRNG seed during cyphering process

Tags: random

I use a home made python script for private local storage using XOR one-time-pad. The key file is generated by using the PRNG provided by the "random" built-in module of python. As the size of the seed is limited in the PRNG, the number of possible seeds is also limited and then introduces a weakness against brute force attack regarding the increasing power of calculation tools.
Do I increase the strength of the script if I change randomnly the seed every two bytes (as an example) ?
The script become slower but it is not a problem in my situation.

fct used : SystemRandom().randint(0,255)

Comment: If you are algorithmically generating your key, you are not using a one time pad. If you can generate your stream from a seed you can save yourself the storage space and just produce it on demand.

Answer (score 0):

`SystemRandom` - which is optional and may not be present - uses the operating system's random number generator according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) which has [not changed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) for Python 3.

> *As the size of the seed is limited in the PRNG, the number of possible seeds is also limited and then introduces a weakness against brute force attack regarding the increasing power of calculation tools*

That's not correct, as `SystemRandom` also relies on entropy collected by the operating system. Any seeds are **commonly** mixed into the state and therefore added to the entropy collected by the random number generator.

However, note the following from the documentation:

> Accordingly, the `seed()` and `jumpahead()` methods have no effect and are ignored.

so adding seed to the entropy pool seems impossible even if adding seeds is generally supported by runtimes / libraries.

It is utterly unclear from documentation what happens with the initial seed in the `SystemRandom([seed])` call, by the way, but you don't seem to use that anyway.

---

Note that you say that you could "randomly change the seed" every 2 bytes. If that seed is indeed truly random then you might want to use that as OTP instead. There is something weird going on if the quality of your random stream depends on the randomness of a different stream of random numbers.

Fortunately for you, on most systems, the system's random number generator is secure whether or not you seed it yourself.

An OTP is almost never the right answer. Try using a stream cipher such as ChaCha20 instead.